# Set up an API on the same server as the frontend

Tags: vue.js, express

I'm developping a website with an access of a single server. I would like implement an express API and a VueJS frontend. According to what I understand, a good practice is to expose this api on *[www.mydomain.com/api](http://www.mydomain.com/api)*

So, my first question is : Is it a good pratice ?

And my second : How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually splitting the front and backend is a good practice. You can have them both hosted on the same domain name tho, no issues with that.

The naming + organization is heavily opinionated to what you need/your way of doing things. Especially since you're using Express and not Ruby on Rails (where everything has a very specific role already).

As of how to achieve this? Make a search on Google. SO is not a place for such question: it's not a tutorial platform. And you already have plenty of resources online for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I did many shearches on Google and ther is thousand of tutorials about how to do an API with express, thousands of tutorials about how to do a VueJS app, but nothing that I found about how to have an API and a frontend hosted on the same domain, and that's why I began to thing that it's not a recommanded implementation...

Comment: @armrib it's just that it's too narrow of a query and not really relevant. You can make it wherever you want. Doesn't matter in terms of building an API. It's more of a devops thing and how you organize your micro services etc.